# Flow gives an error "Cannot assign [value] to this.[property] because property [property] is missing in [class]"

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

This works:

```
// @flow
import React, {Component} from 'react';


type Props = {};

class Delete extends Component<Props> {
  targetElement: null | winndow.HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.targetElement = null; // initialize to null
  }

  handleClick = (e: SyntheticEvent<> & {target: window.HTMLInputElement}) => {
    this.targetElement = (e.target: window.HTMLInputElement).value;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input onClick={this.handleClick} value="hello" />
    );
  }
}

export default Delete;
```

but this doesn't:

```
...
handleClick = (e: SyntheticEvent<> & {target: window.HTMLInputElement}) => {
    this.targetElement = e.target.value;
  };
...
```

The error message is: `Cannot get e.target.value because property value is missing in EventTarget`.

1) I've already typed the "target" property to be `window.HTMLInputElement`, which has a value property, so why does Flow insist that property value is missing in **EventTarget** (why EventTarget?)

In the first place, before I added Flow annotations, the code works great, and there were no console errors about missing properties.

I'm really confused as to how this works - I've read [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2099) and [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/218), and it seems there are a huge range of workarounds/solutions, but I'm not sure why they work. Also, those are 2-3 years old, and I'm not sure if they're still relevant now. I'm new to Flow, but really interested to master it!

Answer (score 5):

Use `SyntheticInputEvent<*>`

```
  handleClick = (e: SyntheticInputEvent<*>) => {
    this.targetElement = e.target.value;
  };
```

or

```
  handleClick = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.targetElement = e.target.value;
  };
```

You might want to [check the docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/events/) and also [cheet sheets](https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/)